# How can I graph the # of emails I receive per day

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-client

Ideally I'd like to do this in Outlook.

I'd like to find a way to look at the # of emails I get in my inbox for each day. This does not have to be real time.

Comment: Create an excel document, input the number of emails you get manually, create a graph

Answer (score 7):

There is this nice tool called [**OutlookStatView**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_statistics.html) made by the awesome guys at NirSoft.

screenshot sample:
[image: tabular statistics of outlook email]

It offers Nice aggregation/summarization, also has save (export) to CSV/XML/HTML functionality, then you can make use of it in Excel for making graphs

> It scans your Outlook mailbox, and display a general statistics about
>   the users that you communicate via emails. For each user/email, the
>   following information is displayed: The number of outgoing messages
>   that you sent to the user (separated by to/cc/bcc), the number of
>   incoming message that the user sent to you, the total size of messages
>   sent by the user, the email client software used by this user, and the
>   time range that you send/received emails with the specified user.

Runs on Windows 2000/XP/Vista/2003/2008/7/8/10.

Supports Any version of Microsoft Outlook, including Outlook 2016.

I'm looking for Mac & Linux alternatives.

Comment: It looks like this breaks down total emails *by user* and not *by day*

Comment: @KyleMit to get a report grouped by a time period - hour, day, week, month, or year; choose the appropriate 'Report Type' field in the 'Scan Options' window.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Microsoft Access, in the External Data tab at the top you can click Outlook Folder as a source and pull all the data from an Outlook folder (in your case "Inbox") into a linked Access table so it updates every time you look at it.

If you're not comfortable with Access then you can click Export to Excel in the same tab at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com) which has some excellent tools for tracking how much you send/receive and from who.

Comment: I don't see any report that will give me the information that I need

Comment: I don't have my machine in front of me but I think if you look in the options, analytics(?) section you can see the graphs.

Comment: This now redirects to yahoo mail?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get all the emails you want to graph in one 'view' in outlook, you can copy the subject, date/time, etc. into excel and then create a graph based on that data.

Comment: But for some reason, the dates are coming out differently if the date is today or another day - this method may not work without some massaging of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally tried any of them, but there's a few Outlook email metric plugins around

- http://www.clearcontext.com/user_guide/scorecard.html
- http://www.outlook-apps.com/email-metrics/

You could also whip your own script up to automate counting emails in Outlook on a schedule and insert the count into an Excel sheet and chart that:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692857.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692913.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a free [Message Statistics by Date](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookStatisticsMessageDate) tool that does exactly what you want. I recommend it because I'm one of its developers. You just specify required Outlook folders and get the report that includes the number of sent/received/total messages as well as their size.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2016 allows you to connect to your exchange server and import your inbox into a spread sheet. You can than make a query using the query tools based on all the fields in the spreadsheet. I am putting the info here as I just ran into this issue myself.

I hope this helps someone who is looking :)

Comment: Please explain with more detail as just saying what you did and giving no details for click this, type that, put code here, press this Excel option to connect it to Exchange, etc. does absolutely nothing for those that know nothing about this functionality. Please simply add more detail to your answer and it's as simple as that... give instructions on what to do and be detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Check my https://statistic.tools/screenshots/

It has various metrics such as Sent, Recieved emails broken downn by various criteria.
Has PDF report generation of the metrics as well.